# Error: 1045 (28000) when connecting to mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql

```
def create_server_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = host_name,
            user = user_name,
            passwd = user_password
        )
        print("database connection successfully completed")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
    return connection

pw = ""
connection = create_server_connection("localhost", "root", pw)
```

I am setting up a connection from Jupyter Notebook to MySQL. I'm using localhost and the root user, which has no password. I got this error message below:

Error: '1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, you are probably using the wrong variable which in your own case is specified `passwd` instead of `password` BUT in the event you still have an error even after this you can also refer to this post from Jetbrains Blog. https://blog.jetbrains.com/datalore/2022/02/14/how-to-run-sql-from-jupyter-notebook-two-easy-ways/

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have the incorrect keyword name for password. It should be

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = host_name,
    user = user_name,
    password = user_password
)
```

Here is the documentation for a simple connection from the MySQL website.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html